# How can I determine the contact point of a collision?

Tags: xna, c#, farseer-physics-engine

I have two Farseer bodies. A static rectangle and a dynamic ball that is flying around. I want to determine where the ball touched the rectangle. I need the exact coordinates of the contact point.

How can I do that? Is there a way to determine the contact point?

[image: Ball touches rectangle]

```
 bool BlueRectangle_OnCollision(Fixture fixtureA, Fixture fixtureB, FarseerPhysics.Dynamics.Contacts.Contact contact)
   {
       if (fixtureB.Body == RedBall)
       {
          Vector2 normal;
          FixedArray2<Vector2> worldPoints;
          contact.GetWorldManifold(out normal, out worldPoints);

          if(contact.Manifold.PointCount >= 1)
          {
            Vector2 contactPoint = worldPoints[0];
          }             
        }

        return true;
    }
```

It works with the following code.

Comment: Note that the contact point will never be mathematically "exact". It will be close enough.

Comment: To answer your additional question: `worldPoints[0]` is the first point (zero-based indexes) and `worldPoints[1]` is the second point (if it exists - re-read my answer for *why* it might exist). `worldPoints[2]` will give you an "index out of range" error (`[2]` refers to the *third* point, but the number of points is limited to two).

Comment: https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-anatomy See *Collision points and the normal*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the list of contacts for each body by walking the contact list (a linked list). Note that a Contact might not actually be touching, it might *almost* be touching. A contact can also be disabled.

```
ContactEdge ce = body.ContactList;
while(ce != null)
{
    Contact contact = ce.Contact;
    if(contact.IsTouching() && contact.Enabled)
    {
        /* ... do stuff with "contact" ... */
    }
    ce = ce.Next;
}
```

You can also get contacts in some of the event handlers, like so:

```
bool MyOnCollisionHandler(Fixture fixtureA, Fixture fixtureB, Contact contact)
{
    /* ... do stuff with "contact" ... */
    return true;
}
```

Note that an event handler can disable a contact if it returns false. Also note that the `OnContact` event triggers when touching first becomes true (so there's no need to check it). See the Farseer source code for `Contact.Update` to see exactly how this works.

A contact can be touching at a single point (as in your example, or a point resting on a line). Or it can be touching along a line between two points (eg: two lines on top of each other). Get these points like so:

```
Vector2 normal;
FixedArray2<Vector2> worldPoints;
contact.GetWorldManifold(out normal, out worldPoints);
```

This gives you a list of contact points (in world space), containing between 0 and 2 points (with the count stored in `contact.Manifold.PointCount`), and the normal (direction) of the contact.

If you strictly need a single point, you can do this:

```
if(contact.Manifold.PointCount >= 1)
{
    Vector2 contactPoint = worldPoints[0];
}
```

Otherwise, use a loop to get either zero, one or both points.

Comment: I still have difficulties to get the contact point. I updated my question with my code and some new questions.

Comment: @Homer_Simpson I've updated my answer to hopefully clarify things.

Comment: I changed my question because I get an error message.

Comment: @Homer_Simpson Apologies. That was a bug in my code. The point count is actually stored in the contact manifold. See my latest edit.

Comment: I tried it but it's not working because contact.Manifold.PointCount is never more than 1.

Comment: @Homer_Simpson Ack. Another simple bug in my code :\ Although I *really* hope you were able to figure that one out on your own! (Please keep in mind that I'm typing these out directly, no IDE.)

Comment: Thanx. It works now.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and used the following pixel collission which I found on the net (sorry i dont know who made that, sorry for no credits :D) and modified it a little.

The 2 Gameobjects checking first, whether they are allowed to collide and then it itereates about the overlaying pixels of object something and target.

```
private bool PixelCollisionDetection(GameObject something, GameObject target)
    {
        // Find the bounds of the rectangle intersection
        int top = Math.Max(something.Rectangle.Top, target.Rectangle.Top);
        int bottom = Math.Min(something.Rectangle.Bottom, target.Rectangle.Bottom);
        int left = Math.Max(something.Rectangle.Left, target.Rectangle.Left);
        int right = Math.Min(something.Rectangle.Right, target.Rectangle.Right);

        if (!target.DoesCollideWith(something.GetType()) && !something.DoesCollideWith(target.GetType()))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!something.Rectangle.Intersects(target.Rectangle))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Check every point within the intersection bounds
        for (int y = top; y < bottom; y++)
        {
            for (int x = left; x < right; x++)
            {
                // Get the color of both pixels at this point
                Color colorA = something.SpriteData[(x - something.Rectangle.Left) +
                                     (y - something.Rectangle.Top) * something.Rectangle.Width];
                Color colorB = target.SpriteData[(x - target.Rectangle.Left) +
                                     (y - target.Rectangle.Top) * target.Rectangle.Width];

                // If both pixels are not completely transparent and attackColors match...
                if (colorA.A != 0 && colorB.A != 0)
                {
                    target.CollisionWith(something, new Vector2(x, y));
                    something.CollisionWith(target, new Vector2(x, y));
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        // No intersection found
        return false;
    }
```

The method CollissionWith(... part is interesting for you, since there I get the exact point of collission, or at least the first, if there are more than one :D

Comment: Hi, Daniel. Could you explain why this is better than using the built in physics tools?

Comment: Well i dont know the farseer physics engine at all but for me it works this way ;) The Pixelcollission returns true only if it is a collission, and false if they are just "close to another" as in your example. I dont know how exact it shall be for your project.